# how to selectively supress list-style-image for some li's

Tags: css, html-lists

In my `ul`, I want list bullets by default, but I'd like to be able to selectively give individual `li`'s a class that causes them to not to utilize the `ul`'s list-style-image.  Right now, my CSS for the given `ul` looks like this:

```
.monthly-menu td ul {
    margin: 0 15px 15px 20px;
    list-style-image: url('../images/menus/menu-bullet.png');
}
```

Is there a style I can add to `li`'s so that they won't inherit the bullet image from the `ul`?

Comment: have you tried `li.whatever {list-style-image: none;}`?

Comment: no, but i will.  Like i say, noob question. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a specific class/id to the `li` and then add `list-style-image: none` to the CSS for the corresponding class/id. Example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="noImage">Text here.</li>
    <li>Text here.</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('../images/menus/menu-bullet.png');
}

.noImage {
    list-style-image: none;
}
```

​
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YrEM4/1/